# Command to focus recently used editor group

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would love to know if there's a command I could bind, that would allow me to switch focus to the recently used editor group, like so:

```
this is the initial focus state
|  1  | (2) |  3  |

here I'm switching focus to the 3'rd window
|  1  |  2  | (3) |

after the "Focus recently used group" command, the focus goes back to 2'nd window
|  1  | (2) |  3  |
```

Initially I thought the `workbench.action.focusPreviousGroup` would do the trick, however it doesn't work for more than 2 editor groups.

Comment: What you want is to focus the next most recently used editor group, for which there doesn't appear to be a command.

Answer (score 0):

you can look for the command

```
workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex1
```

default key bind is: `Alt+1`

this selects a particular editor in a group.

Search key bind GUI for: `editor index` for other similar commands

---

If you want to switch groups use:

```
workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup
workbench.action.focusSecondEditorGroup
....
```

Default key bind: `Ctrl+1`, `Ctrl+2`, .....

Search key bind GUI for: `focus group`

command naming is a bid strange, I would prefer

- `workbench.action.focusEditorGroup1`
- `workbench.action.focusEditorGroup2`
- ....

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the response anyway!